# How to reference a package's public EXCEPTION via dblink?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Good day,

We have an Oracle 11g PLSQL package that defines a bunch of standard exceptions used across our code.

It's compiled under schema `owner` of database `db_main` in a PLSQL package called `pkg_exception`.

They are defined in the package header like so:

```
E_SOME_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(E_SOME_EXCEPTION, -20002);
```

Referencing these exceptions within code compiled in `db_main` is easy:

```
RAISE pkg_exception.E_SOME_EXCEPTION;
```

However, I want to raise this exception through a dblink from database `db_aux`. The dblink (`db_main_reader`) connects to a schema in `db_main` that can see and use `owner.pkg_exception` but I keep getting syntax errors when compiling:

```sql
-- 1. Obviously won't work.
RAISE pkg_exception.E_SOME_EXCEPTION;
-- PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_EXCEPTION.E_SOME_EXCEPTION' must be declared

-- 2. Typical syntax for referencing an object via dblink.
RAISE pkg_exception.E_SOME_EXCEPTION@db_main_reader;
-- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:     . ;

-- 3. Nope.
RAISE pkg_exception@db_main_reader.E_SOME_EXCEPTION;
-- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:     . ;
```

I can reference and use every other public reference in the package's header through the dblink:

```sql
-- Variables
v_foo pkg_exception.FOO@db_main_reader;

-- Functions
pkg_exception.get_foo@db_main_reader(...);

-- Procedures
pkg_exception.foo@db_main_reader(...);
```

Just not the exceptions. Does anyone know how exceptions are referenced through a dblink in Oracle's PLSQL? Or would I have to define exceptions locally (in `db_aux`)?

---

**Solution**

@Martin Schapendonk suggested using a public synonym across the dblink and this resolves the issue:

```sql
-- Inside "db_aux":
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM pkg_exception FOR owner.pkg_exception@db_main_reader;

BEGIN
  RAISE pkg_exception.E_SOMETHING;
  
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN pkg_exception.E_SOMETHING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pkg_exception.get_error_message(sqlcode));
END;
/
```

Output:

```
Elapsed: 00:00:00.057
You raised the "E_SOMETHING" exception.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I think they have to be redefined locally.

Comment: Does it work if you create a synonym for the package across the dblink? And if you don't define the exception in dbaux, can you catch it with a `when others then` and log how it is raised in dbaux?

Comment: Excellent suggestion Martin. You should add it as answer because that works.